# Is it possible to compress a image by sampling a given image with various different patterns?

Tags: image, image-processing, encoding

Say I have a image that is 64x64 and this contains various different patterns broken up into 8x8 sections, this will be the sampled image.
And then say we have another image that is 1024x1024 and we want to check each 8x8 section of the sampled image and get a value of how similar this section this is to a section of the sampled image.
Then when we go to encode this image, we would put the index of the sampled image where it was most similar.
Is this a acceptable method of lossy compression?

Comment: Sure, if it works for your needs. Why not? Got some examples and code to share?

Comment: What do you mean by "acceptable method of lossy compression"? What is acceptable to you? You need to work out your acceptance criteria for your project; what is "acceptable" to one person might not be to another.

Comment: This might be interesting if you learn the sampled image — find the 64 patches of 8x8 pixels that yield the smallest reconstruction error. But in general, 64 patches is a very small amount, note that an 8x8 patch can contain 256^64 different configurations (not considering color), this is an astronomical number!

Comment: I was't implying that I do every possible configuration but more like, use some common patterns and see how the image comes out.